# use script from a bootstrap template in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a singular page web project in Angular, in this project I have imported a graphic template with all assets, css and js files. Both the css an sccript files are imported in angular.json in this way:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/app.js",
          "src/assets/js/demodata.js",
          "src/assets/js/demo.js",
          "src/assets/js/vendor.js",
          "src/assets/js/app.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/demodata.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/demo.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/vendor.min.js"
        ]
```

but in appComponent.html when I call

```
 form class="form-funcion"
```

where form-function is in demo.js, 
I don't get the expected behavior. Where is the problem?

Comment: Could it be that you have it as `form-funcion` in HTML (no `t`) and `form-function` in `demo.js`?

Comment: sorry, the call with t, I missed in the question, but the correct is form class="form-function". furm-function is an example,  it does not work even when other functions are called.

Comment: Could it be you're missing CSS files in the `styles` array?

Comment: the CSS ' styles ' work done, the problem is the script